# Update solr document using http get method

Tags: solr, updates

Using `curl` this can be done with: (update price field with value 100)

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"1","price":{"set":100}}]
```

How to do the same using http get method? I need to fill the XXXX in the following:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update?stream.body=XXXX&commit=true
```

The following does not work:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="id">1</field><field name="price" update="set">100</field></doc></add>&commit=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the stream.body does not need to be xml, so this works:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update?stream.body=[{"id":"1","price":{"set":100}}]&commit=true
```